# What is the type of this encrypted password?

Tags: encryption, decode, password-encryption

I found encrypted text in my code and I want to decode it. Or I want to know the encryption type here is the found hash

```
1KrECjWpJWocpuzB2aADQVrCaKvNM8kgUp
```

PS: I tried to decode it using hash online decoder and many sites like :

1. https://hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx
2. http://www.md5online.org/

I had no chance to decode it it said "BAD FORMAT".

Comment: There are literally infinite possible encoding/hashing/encryption algorithms. It may be none, some or a mix. You've given literally no context. Way too broad, voting to close.

Comment: i wanna know the encryption type that's all

Comment: Did you read and understand what I said?

Comment: yeah sure thats why i commented back i thought that there is perl/python script can figure out the hash type :S

Comment: I don't think you understood what I said...  What reason do you have to believe that it is a hash?  It could be a random binary string.  Or your grandma's shopping list.  You haven't given any context at all.  Where did you get it?  What created it?  Get what I'm saying?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer well ok i will keep it in mind for next question thanks.

Comment: I'm voting close this question as off-topic because questions about breaking encryption/hash without giving any context is impossible in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is some indicator in your string of what kind of string it is, we may not be able to help. It looks too long for MD5 (34 instead of 32), but it could be MD5 and two characters of checksum.

Some hashing algorithms work by applying a mix of algorithms, or the same algorithm several times, to make brute-force searching harder.

Note that while encryption can be reversed, it is either hard or impossible to reverse a hash, depending on the computational complexity of building your own [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_tables). Thus, MD5 is not impossible, and Bcrypt with sufficient rounds is so complex that it can be called impossible for all intents and purposes.

Your best bet is to look at the code that created it and figure it out from there.

Comment: unfortunately i found this string into my script.js file so i thought i can figure out the meaning of it

Comment: @Un1xCr3w: where did it come from? It does not just "appear" there, generally `;-)`.

Comment: i just found it like this 
'1KrECjWpJWocpuzB2aADQVrCaKvNM8kgUp', '1AfXYawNt7d5HfyW8N2A2NG18LHqHv1KaS', '1QCYhXMqpSiTZFd4VBeBts39twRNdjcyAJ',  in my js file